# Redirect unlogged guest

Tags: reactjs, redux, fetch, laravel-sanctum

I use React with Sanctum. I made atheAPI and I'm using middleware to protect that. Problem is that it only protects the API but it doesn't protect components. I want to implement a redirect. If a user visits a component which needs to log in - he will be redirected to the login route. My first idea was that I can fetch the user's data and if this data doesn't  exist, the guest will be redirected.

```
{user.user.id ? '' : <Redirect to="/login" /> }
```

But it isn't a good method for me. In 1 component I have all routing - login, register, etc too. Component which don't require a user will be logged in. And if I try fetch user's data I have 401 error.Any other idea how can I solve my problem?
@Update

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await axiosConfig.get('api/user');
    const json = response.data;
    return json;
}
export const getUser = () =>
    async (dispatch) => {
        const user = await fetchData()
       dispatch(actions.setUser(user));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Pseudo-security. After a user logs in, set some flag in e.g. local, session... storage to indicate that a user is logged in. Create a dedicated component that checks whether a user is logged in, and use it as a wrapper for your "protected" components.

```
const Authenticated = ({children}) => {
  const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('loggedIn');
  return isLoggedIn ? children : <Redirect to='/login' />
}
```

Use it:

```
<Authenticated>
  <MyProtectedComponent />
</Authenticated>
```

Comment: ok, it should work but I use Redux and I must request to the server. If it return error 401, my app will crush.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Private route component.

**PrivateRoute** Component

```js
const PrivateRoute = ({ children, ...rest }) => {
  const { user } = useUser(); // Some hook or a way to get logged in user. You can get token from localStorage as well. 
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={({ location }) => {
        if (user?.id) {
          return children;
        }
        return (
          <Redirect
            to={{
              pathname: '/login',
              state: { from: location }, // This is added in case if you want to redirect user to login with existing query params
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
};
```

**AppRouter** Component

```js
const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute path="/">
          <Route path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
        </PrivateRoute>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

**EDIT**
Updated the fetchData function.

**fetchData**

```js
const fetchData = async () => {
    try{
      const response = await axiosConfig.get('api/user');
      const json = response.data;
      return json;
    } catch(error) {
      if(error.response.status === 401) {
        // Handle 404 here
      }
    }
    
    return null; // In case if error and try doesn't return anything
}
```

Comment: it doesn;t sove my problem. I want to store user details in a redux store. So I must request to the server and fetch data. Problem is that if it return 401 error, it'll crush my app.

Comment: You can handle the 401 in response. You must have some single Gateway of API call using axios, fetch, or GraphQL or something else? You can handle the 401 response code there. 

In place of `const { user } = useUser();`. You can import user from reduce in place of this code.

Comment: Do add your current code which will help to understand the question in a better way.

Comment: Updated the `fetchData` function to handle `401`.

Comment: For better clarity can you check what are you getting in `catch` error object? just to verify you are getting the same object.

Comment: Context is very simple. I fetch user's details via db and I dispatch them to Redux store. I use that in a few of components - to display name, to mark a user's article, and so on. So good idea is use that to check that data exist. Even if I  won't  to use for a deferent purpose, mixed localstorage and redux is not good idea.